# Experiencing difficulties running a gatsby project on yarn

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gatsby, yarnpkg

I am trying to help a friend with its gatsby template, each time I tried to run the gatsby project, I get several errors.

```sh
C:\Users\Thosyn Pax\Desktop\Project\Sarvesh\Sarvesh\Superprops\Superprops>yarn gatsby-dev
yarn run v1.22.4
$ yarn workspace gatsby-landing run dev
$ gatsby develop
success open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.474s
success load plugins - 99.856s
success onPreInit - 0.400s
success initialize cache - 0.175s
success copy gatsby files - 1.584s
success onPreBootstrap - 3.519s
success createSchemaCustomization - 0.129s
success source and transform nodes - 16.371s
success building schema - 13.086s
success createPages - 0.022s
success createPagesStatefully - 2.229s
success onPreExtractQueries - 0.010s
success update schema - 0.379s
success extract queries from components - 39.358s
success write out requires - 0.879s
success write out redirect data - 0.019s
warn The icon(src/images/favicon.png) you provided to 'gatsby-plugin-manifest' is not
 square.
The icons we generate will be square and for the best results we recommend you
success Build manifest and related icons - 2.713s
success onPostBootstrap - 2.757s
⠀
info bootstrap finished - 266.442s
⠀

 ERROR 

Processing C:/Users/Thosyn Pax/Desktop/Project/Sarvesh/Sarvesh/Superprops/Superprops/packages/common/src/assets/image/agency/blog/blog-img1.png failed
```

Original error:

```sh
  WorkerError: Processing C:/Users/Thosyn Pax/Desktop/Project/Sarvesh/Sarvesh/Superpr  ops/Superprops/packages/common/src/assets/image/agency/blog/blog-img1.png failed
  Original error:

  - jobs-manager.js:316 exports.enqueueJob
    [Superprops]/[gatsby]/dist/utils/jobs-manager.js:316:23

  - runMicrotasks

  - task_queues.js:97 processTicksAndRejections
    internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5


not finished run queries - 2.861s
not finished Generating image thumbnails - 2.512s
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
Arguments: C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js run dev
Directory: C:\Users\Thosyn Pax\Desktop\Project\Sarvesh\Sarvesh\Superprops\Superprops\packages\landing-gatsby
Output:

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/workspace for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```